# How to solve the below recurrence relation question

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, recurrence, recursive-datastructures

Consider a recursive algorithm that break a given problem into five parts. Out of these five parts the algorithm utilizes three parts and discards two parts. The chosen parts are broken into five again and the same process is recursively repeated until the problem size is 1. Once the problem size is 1, the individual parts are recombined.

1. Write a recurrence relation for the above algorithm. Please state your assumptions.
2. Solve the recurrence relation developed in part 1 above using the Substitution Method. Specify the guess and the method you used in deciding that guess.

Please let know the answer even if you know only for the part 1.
Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a homework question. Please include the steps you have already taken to try to solve it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: The problem is under-specified, since we don't know how much work it takes to divide the input into five parts, select which three to make recursive calls on, or to combine the three results from the recursive calls. You will need to make assumptions about that.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what you mean by the "parts" of the problem. If the initial problem is some sort of data structure, particularly an array of numbers, then in the first part you would divide the structure into five categories based on certain properties of the numbers, and then discard two of those categories and repeat the process on the remaining 3. Just to be clear, is this the exact wording of a homework problem you were given? It would be good to have some information.